# Need a good architecture for rules of validations

Tags: c#, validation

I hope you guys can give me some good suggestions. I am thinking how to make a good architecture for C# development. I am trying my best to explain scenarios because im not good at english:

1) Two classes: Blue Bank and Red Bank

2) Third class : Rules Of Validations

3) Blue and Red Banks have several fields (values) such as AccountNumber, Amount, InvoicePeriod etc... Example here (xml):

Blue Bank

```
  <AccountNumber>Maria 5987593457</AccountNumber>
  <Amount>200.00</Amount>
  <InvoicePeriod>1</InvoicePeriod>
```

Red Bank

```
  <AccountNumber>8529458</AccountNumber>
  <Amount>300.00</Amount>
  <InvoicePeriod>0</InvoicePeriod>
```

Red/Blue Banks have some same rules of validations like Amount fields that must be numberic. But Red/Blue Banks have different rules of validations -- AccountNumber field must be alphanumberic in Blue Bank whereas AccountNumber must be numberic in Red Bank otherwise failed. InvoicePeriod field must be default 1 in Red Bank whereas it must be default 0 in Blue Bank otherwise failed.

My idea is:

I want to create each class of Red / Blue Bank for different rules of validation and then i also create a rules of validation class for the same rules that Blue/Red banks have.

**My code here:**

**Blue Bank class:**

- Validate AccountNumber that must be alphanumberic otherwise failed
- Validate InvoicePeriod that must be default 1 otherwise failed

**Red Bank class:**

- Validate AccountNumber that must be numberic otherwise failed
- Validate InvoicePeriod that must be default 0 otherwise failed

**RulesOfValidation class**

- Validate Amount that must be numberic (same rules for both Red / Blue Bank classes)

How does it work with dictonary <,> with these classes? Or any better suggestion with your example codes?

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For Validation you can take a look at the [`IDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) interface, see an example [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validating-with-the-idataerrorinfo-interface-cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

First  Create abstract class  Bank

```
abstract class Bank
{
    #region fields
    private List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>();
    #endregion

    #region publioc methods
    public virtual void Validate()
    {
        ValidateRulesAtributes();
    }

    #endregion

    #region helper methods
    private void ValidateRulesAtributes()
    {
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(this, null, null); //ValidationContext -> Reference System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
        var result = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, result, true);



        result.ForEach(p => { errorMessages.Add(p.ErrorMessage); });

        if (errorMessages.Any())
            throw new Exception(errorMessages.Aggregate((m1, m2) => String.Concat(m1, Environment.NewLine, m2)));
    }

    protected void Validate(List<string> messages)
    {
        if (errorMessages == null)
            errorMessages = new List<string>();

        if (messages != null)
            messages.ForEach(p => { errorMessages.Add(p); });
        ValidateRulesAtributes();

    }
    #endregion
    #region properties
    //Abstract to indicate Validation atributes 

    public abstract string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public abstract double Amount { get; set; }
    public abstract int InvoicePeriod { get; set; }
    #endregion

}
```

Second Create Red and Blue Bank with data anotations

```
class BlueBank : Bank
    {
        //All is ok, no validate 
        public override string AccountNumber { get; set; }

        public override double Amount { get; set; }

        public override int InvoicePeriod { get; set; }

    }
class RedBank : Bank
    {
        [Required()]
        public override string AccountNumber { get; set; }

        public override double Amount { get; set; }
        [Range(0,0)]
        public override int InvoicePeriod { get; set; }


        public override void Validate()
        {
            List<string> errors=new List<string>();
            if (AccountNumber != "Test")
                errors.Add("Worng Account");
            base.Validate(errors);
        }

    }
```

Use Atributes to validate ranges, required,etc..
Override Validate() to complex validations

This a simple example

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RedBank red = new RedBank();
            red.AccountNumber = "Test";

            red.Amount=0;
            red.Validate(); //this No fail

            red.InvoicePeriod = 3; //This Fail;
            red.Validate(); 

            red.AccountNumber = "PD";
            red.Validate(); //this fal:

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

[Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) is a good option for your problem. You can create a specification class for common bank rules and others specification classes for each specific need.

There is some c# libraries for this pattern:

- https://github.com/giacomelli/KissSpecifications
- https://github.com/danielcrenna/specifications

Comment: didn't know that patterns, its pretty sweet

Answer (score 3):

I would go with `IRule` interface with `Validate()` method which could be implemented in concrete validation classes which could contain validation logic. Then you will be able to precess several custom rules in bank. Pass the list of `IRule` type objects to bank class and run `Validate()` on each passing bank parameters. So each bank could validate itself based on passed rules.

```
interface IRule
{
    bool Validate(Bank someBank);
}

abstract class Bank
{
    public string AccountNumber;
    public string Amount;
    public string InvoicePeriod;

    private List<IRule> listOfRules = new List<IRule>();

    public void ValidateAllRules(){
        foreach (var ite in listOfRules){
            ite.Validate(this);
            //if validation will not pass then I don't know what you want to do ;)
        }
    }

    public void AddRule(IRule rule)
    {
        listOfRules.Add(rule);
    }
}

class RedBank : Bank
{
    public RedBank(){
        listOfRules.Add(new SimpleRule());
        listOfRules.Add(new SimpleRule2());
    }
}

class SimpleRule : IRule
{
    public bool Validate(Bank someBank)
    {
        return someBank.AccountNumber.Contains("567");
    }
}

class SimpleRule2 : IRule
{
    public bool Validate(Bank someBank)
    {
        return someBank.Amount.Contains(".") && someBank.InvoicePeriod.Contains("-");
    }
}
```

Comment: I like ur suggestion. Maybe can you give me a good example codes here so that i can see a clear picture in my mind. If you dont mind :-)

Comment: Something like this, looks a bit like specification pattern that giacomelli posted.

Comment: Instead of thank you comment you should accept or up vote response ;)